# C# Select Distinct Values from IGrouping

Tags: c#, lambda

I have two classes:

```
class Foo 
{ 
    public Bar SomeBar { get; set; } 
}

class Bar
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

I have a list of Foos that I group together:

```
var someGroup = from f in fooList
                orderby f.SomeBar.Name ascending
                group f by f.SomeBar.Name into Group
                select Group;
```

How can I get the list of the distinct Bars from someGroup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Will there potentially be more than one Bar with the same name? If so, it's tricky. If not, you could just change it to:

```
var grouped = from f in fooList
              orderby f.SomeBar.Name ascending
              group f by f.SomeBar into Group
              select Group;

var bars = grouped.Select(group => group.Key);
```

Alternatively, if you only want one Bar per *name*, you could stick with your original query, but change the last bit:

```
var someGroup = from f in fooList
                orderby f.SomeBar.Name ascending
                group f by f.SomeBar.Name into Group
                select Group;

var bars = someGroup.Select(group => group.First().SomeBar);
```

This will take the first Foo in each group, and find its Bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you define "being distinct" by a special `Equals` implementation for `Bar`, you could use:

```
var result = someGroup.SelectMany(x => x.Select(t => t.SomeBar)).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

People asked similar questions before, So I have made this combining everyone's knowledge:

```
var newlist<T2> = oldlist<T1>.GroupBy(g => g.distinct_var).Select(g => g.First()) //a
                 .Select(r=> new T2() {var1=r.va1, var2=r.var2 ...etc}).ToList(); //b
```

What it does is:

a. First line selects distinct items of your choice, which is what you wanted.

b. Second line converts old type1 to new type2 by constructing new T2 list.

Maybe overkilled for your question, just chop out things you don't need.